# VSTS group permissions for teams

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying out Visual Studio Team Services. My project will have multiple teams, each working on a separate component for the project. No team should have any means of altering another team's work items, code, repository, bugs, etc.

I created a general group in the project called Project Teams, which denied access to changing project permissions, but allowed non-project permissions. I then created a team called Team1 and made the Team1 group a member of Project Teams. I went to the Version Control for Team1 and created a specific repository called SystemTest. Under Security, I added the Team1 group. When I leave the page and come back, Team1 is no longer listed as a group for SystemTest.

What am I missing? Or am I going about this the wrong way?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

After adding the group, I changed one of the permissions and saved. When I left the page and came back, the group was still in the list.
I noticed there is now no direct means of removing the group. I selected the group and clicked Clear explicit permissions and saved. I left the page and came back and the group was removed from the list.